# Regex to limit length of title

Tags: regex

Title cannot contain only numbers or symbols. Title should start with an    alphabet and it should contain minimum 3 and maximum 15 characters.

I tried below regex but not working.

```
    /^([A-Za-z])[\w!#\$%\&*\)\(+=._-]{3,15}+$/g
```

Comment: Your regex somehow implies that your description of the problem does not include all requirements. Or does it?

Comment: Change `{3,15}` to `{2,14}`. You already matched one character in `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: No it is giving me invalid expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z].{2,14}$
```

fulfills the requirements as you worded them. If that's not what you actually want (I'm looking at your regex here) please clarify.

Comment: I came up with the exact same regex, added [a regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD9pR2/1) as well

Comment: @Jan Thanks, nice demo.

Comment: Actually I am also trying that online . I actually want "Title cannot contain only numbers or symbols. Title should start with an alphabet" and minimum 3 and maximum 15 characters should be allowed .

Comment: @user3032373 that's exactly what the regex Jan and I gave you does.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be as below in case of allowing special characters: 
   !#$%&*()+=_-.

```
^[A-Za-z][\w\!\#\$\%\&*\)\(+=\._-]{3,15}$
```

In case you want to allow all the special character then use @timegeb's reply i.e

```
^[A-Za-z].{2,14}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put limit on total size use positive look-ahead to limit size as below

```
^(?=^.{3,15}$)([A-Za-z].*)$
```

**Explanation**

```
^          # At the start of the string
(?=        # matches
^.{3,15}$  # 3 to 15 characters from start to end
)([A-Za-z] # with an alphabet
.*         # and characters
)$         # to the end
```